# Unable to export Testset on github from Botium

Tags: chatbot

i am able to create a testset in  local repository in botium box. how to create a export my testset on github. i can see there are two option register in gitrepository and register shared folder.  but unable to export the testset created in botium. #BOTIUM-BOX

Comment: you have to register and connect your git repository to botium box first.

Comment: Regisered and connected to my git repository by adding the url of my repo. ican see a readme.md file in repository but can't see my tes set

Comment: i recommend reading this article to get an idea how to use a git repo with botium box: https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/33234/Best+Practice+Test+Case+Development